# Include a file within a folder in an Arduino library

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm currently writing an Arduino library and I want to include files in a subdirectory within the library folder. More specifically, I want the files to be accesible from the Arduino sketch.

This is my directory structure:

```
MyLib/MyLib.cpp
MyLib/MyLib.h
MyLib/Extra/SomeNiceFunctions.cpp
MyLib/Extra/SomeNiceFunctions.h
```

This is how I'm trying to include the file:

```
#include <MyLib.h>
#include <Extra/SomeNiceFunctions.h>
```

Obviously this is wrong because of the way the IDE is including the library folders. What else should I try? I could split the Extra folder to another "Library" (another folder) but that's not what I'm after.

**EDIT:** This is the error I'm getting `undefined reference to 'font8x8'`. This is defined in `Extra/SomeNiceFunctions.h`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use

```
#include <MyLib.h>
#include <Extra/SomeNiceFunctions.h>
```

instead use

```
#include <arduinolib.h>
#include "MyLib.h"
#include "Extra/SomeNiceFunctions.h"
```

Using angle-brackets, the compiler looks in the standard-folders for include-files. You want your custom files in your working directory.

Comment: All files are in my Arduino library folder, not in the sketch folder, but you are correct!

Comment: That's the message I get: `undefined reference to 'font8x8'`. font8x8 is defined in `SomeNiceFunctions.h`. Everything works correctly if I simply copy all the files into the main library folder.

Comment: Are you including the arduino-specific headers, too? Are you linking with the libraries?

Comment: Yes, everything works correctly if I put every file in the main library folder (`SomeNiceFunctions.h` and `SomeNiceFunctions.cpp` in `MyLib`). My guess is that the IDE is looking for `.h` files in every folder in the library folder but not inside folders in those folders. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Try to include your your arduino libraries using angle-brackets, like I edited in my post.

Comment: I did, to no avail. I don't think there is a solution to this, other than just pasting all the files in the root library folder.

Comment: Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Couldn't find any pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding including Arduion/Energia libraries that are in Arduino/Energia subfolders:
Look where your main include file is (eg. arduino.h / energia.h) and go up in the directory structure with ..\ or downwards until you get to the desired h file you want to include.
eg.
I have:
..hardware\cores\cc3200\energia.h
..hardware\libraries\SPI\SPI.h

In order to use in a .cpp file the SPI.h functions, I have to add:
`#include <energia.h>`
followed by 
`#include <..\..\libraries\SPI\SPI.h`

Answer (score -1):

Borrowing from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504211/is-it-possible-to-include-a-library-from-another-library-using-the-arduino-ide),

> The include path includes the sketch's directory, the target directory
>   (/hardware/core//) and the avr include directory
>   (/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/), as well as any library directories
>   (in /hardware/libraries/) which contain a header file which is
>   included by the main sketch file.

Try

```
// in myProject.ino
#include <arduinolib.h>
#include "MyLib.h"

// in Mylib.h
#include "./extra/SomeNiceFunctions.h"
```

Comment: 'SomeNiceFunctions.h' is not automatically included because it is in a subfolder within a library folder.

Comment: In the last sentence, it specifies that the header needs to be included by the main sketch file.  Have you tried adding the header to the main sketch?  Have you tried including SomeNiceFunctions in MyLib.h ?

Answer (score -1):

I had some an issue with this.  I just wanted a simple solution and while writing a library in CPP is the correct way - I took a sketch - say robo.ino file and added it to a simple library include - so that there was just one file in the library under a folder called Robot - robo.h

```
├── sketchesfolder
├── libraries
│   ├── robot
│   │   ├── robot.h
├── robotsketch
│   ├── Move.ino
```

Now in the Move.ino - I just include the file

```
#include <robo.h>
```

The only thing you need to add for simple functions is a prototype declaration - or make sure your functions are ordered by first use.

So for example - put Setup() at the bottom and a function like:

```
 void halt(int wait);
```

as a prototype definition at the head of the robo.h file

It allows you to share a sketch as common code without converting it to a CPP lib.  But you should really do that of course.